# How to contribute to SAPUI 5 (OpenUI 5) framework

Tags: open-source, sapui5

I found a lot of places at source code of SAPUI5 (OpenUI5) where I can improve performance and readability. But I didn't found the way how to contribute.
Could someone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forking and contributing is now possible:
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contribute-code

Answer (score 4):

[OpenUI5 is on Github](https://github.com/SAP/openui5) with an Apache 2.0 licence. Originally the internal build process of UI5 was more complex than the team at SAP would like.

In Oct 2014 they simplified it (so that we can build from source too) and have place the sources on Github so that we can fork and contribute as with other Github-based projects. See the "[Contributing](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contribute-code)" section in the repo for more information.